# How can I pass the argument to docker-compose.yml using shell file

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose, docker-ucp

I have docker-compose.yml as follows:

```
version: '2'

services:
  eureka-server:
    image: some-dtr-name/some-orgname/some-reponame:some-versionname
    mem_limit: somememory
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: some-profile
      JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
    ports:
    - "some-port:some-port"
    restart: always
    networks:
    - cloud

networks:
  cloud:
   driver: bridge
```

I want to pass some-dtr-name,some-orgname,some-reponame,some-versionname,somememory,some-profile,some-profile,some-port as a aurgument to docker-compose file.
I am doing this task using shell file.

```
#!/bin/bash
some-dtr-name="$1"
some-orgname="$2"
some-reponame="$3"
some-versionname="$4"
somememory="$5"
some-profile="$6"
some-profile="$7"
some-port="$8"

docker-compose up
```

How can I do this task ??

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose supports the environment variable substitution, using the `${}` syntax: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution

So if you have the environment variable `some_port` defined, before you run `docker-compose`, you can then just refer to it as `${some_port}` in your docker-compose file.

```
ports:
- "${some_port}:${some_port}"
```

Another thing to note is that the variable  names in your sample code contain dashes `-`, which is not valid in `bash`

> name A word consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and beginning with an alphabetic character or an underscore. Also referred to as an identifier.

you have to use underscore character `_` instead.